# How to created keyboard functions that lets the user move left and right in Java

Tags: java, swing, keyboard

This is code. I'm trying to create mini tennis, but right now I just want to learn how to move the bottom bar left and right.

> **panelObject Class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class panelObject extends JPanel
{

int ballx = 50;
int bally = 50;

int barx = 405;
int bary = 405;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);//creates the color of th background

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);// creates the color of the object
    g.fillOval(ballx,bally,50,50); // creates the size and shape of the object


    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(barx,bary, 50,50);
}


}
```

> **TennisGame class**

```
public class TennisGame
{

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Tennis"); //Create a JFrame object, its basically the window
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //This sets the default close operation, you don't really need to understand it, just make sure you have it
    panelObject object = new panelObject(); // creates a panel object to draw on
    f.add(object); // this adds the panel we created to the window
    f.setSize(640,480); // this sets the size of the window
    f.setVisible(true); // this shows the window

    //this for loop just loops 540 times
    //each time through the loop, we increase the x value of our rectangle 
    for (int i = 0; i < 540; i++)
    {
        //increase the x value of the rectangle; x was declared in the panelObeject class
        object.ballx += 1;
        //repaint will redraw the screen with the updated rectangle position
        object.repaint();

        //this whole try catch will pause the program for a while so it doesn't draw everything so fast
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(3); // time duration
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

}

//update animation
public void update (long timePassed) 
{

}

}
```

Comment: Please do some prior research and try writing a solution even if it doesn't work.

Comment: what is your point?

Comment: If you look for `Java keyboard events`, you'll find many similar questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421014/keyboard-events-java

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the Bar object move we must

- Capture the Inputed key
- Decide what that key is an update the bar's properties
- redraw the bar

Note: This isn't the most efficient ways of creating such a program, and you might want to consider creating a tick and paint method that are called a designated number of times per second (Like 60, AKA 60 FPS/TPS).

tick being to update the Tennis games information and 
paint to render that 'information' accordingly

*here is all of your code, i edited some parts and created comments.*

```
static panelObject object; //Declares the JPanel Object to draw on as a Global Variable
public static void main (String[] args)
{

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Tennis"); //Create a JFrame object, its basically 
                                                                the window
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //This sets the default close operation, you don't really need to understand it, just make sure you have it
    object = new panelObject(); // initializing the global panel object to draw on



    f.add(object); // this adds the panel we created to the window
    f.setSize(640,480); // this sets the size of the window
    f.setVisible(true); // this shows the window

    f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { // This Method is called when any key is pressed on the keyboard and stores the key pressed as 'e'

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) //if the pressed key is 'a' then move left 
            {
                System.out.println("left");   
                object.barx -= object.ballSpeed; //We know that the key is a so move the bar to the left
            }

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) //if the pressed key is 'd' then move right
            {
                System.out.println("right");
                object.barx += object.ballSpeed; //We know that the key is d so move the bar to the right
            }

            object.repaint();//Repaints to the screen(Not the Best place to do this,but will work)
        }
    });




    //this for loop just loops 540 times
    //each time through the loop, we increase the x value of our circle 
    for (int i = 0; i < 540; i++)
    {
        //increase the x value of the rectangle; x was declared in the panelObeject class
        object.ballx += 1;
        //repaint will redraw the screen with the updated rectangle position
        object.repaint();

        //this whole try catch will pause the program for a while so it doesn't draw everything so fast
        try 
        {


            Thread.sleep(3); // time duration

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { 

        } 

   }
}

//update animation
public static void update (long timePassed) 
{
    object.repaint();

}
```

*Here is the panelObject class, i didnt change much*

```
public class panelObject extends JPanel{
int ballSpeed = 3; // The ball has a speed property so when it moves you don't hard code the value in (Bad Practice especially in very large programs)
int ballx = 50;
int bally = 50;

int barx = 405;
int bary = 405;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);//creates the color of th background

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);// creates the color of the object
    g.fillOval(ballx,bally,50,50); // creates the size and shape of the object


    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(barx,bary, 50,50);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdpater()  is not working. TennisGame.java:56: error: cannot find symbol